# Cancel button for google plus sign-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, google-plus

In twitter when the user pressed the cancel button it is redirected to this URL:

`URL/verify?denied=TOKEN`

therefore you can determine it by the `denied` in the URL.

In google+ sign-in, is there a way to detect the cancel button in the sign-in page or detect the close button for the javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the callback function, an error code is returned if the user rejects the consent dialog.

An example callback that checks for access_denied, indicating the user rejected the consent dialog:

```
  function onSignInCallback(authResult) {
    if (authResult['access_token']) {
      // success
    } else if (authResult['error']) {
      if (authResult['error'] == 'immediate_failed'){
        // This is perfectly normal, the user reached the site and was not logged in
        // However, if the user should be signed in on this page, it would be
        // appropriate to have an error here
      }
      if (authResult['error'] == 'access_denied'){
        // The user cancelled out of the dialog.
      }

      // There was an error, which means the user is not signed in.
      // As an example, you can handle by writing to the console:
      console.log('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
    }
    console.log('authResult', authResult);
  };
```

Comment: would u able to determine if the user presses the close button?